# Disqus email notifications open localhost instead of the real website

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, disqus

I am using Gastbyjs with Disqus plugin for commenting function. I followed the [instruction here](https://disqus.com/profile/signup/intent/)

[image]

I received emails about comments in my blog, but when I clicked the button "Reply to XXX" it opens.

[image: Dis]

> https://localhost:8000/blogs/article-name

[image]

I think I missed some configuration for this.

### Update 1

Here is the code where I use the config:

```
export const BlogPostTemplate = ({
  content,
  contentComponent,
  description,
  tags,
  title,
  helmet,
}) => {
  const PostContent = contentComponent || Content;

  const disqusConfig = {
    shortname: process.env.GATSBY_DISQUS_NAME,
    config: { identifier: title },
  };
```

### Update 2

I managed to use Reach/Router to access Location

I installed reach/router and I updated my code:

```
import { Location } from "@reach/router";

export const BlogPostTemplate = ({
  content,
  contentComponent,
  description,
  tags,
  title,
  helmet,
  location
}) => {
  const PostContent = contentComponent || Content;
  console.log('--------------location---------');
  console.log(location);
  const disqusConfig = {
    url: location.href,
    shortname: process.env.GATSBY_DISQUS_NAME,
    config: { identifier: title },
  };

  return (
    <section className="section">
      {helmet || ""}
      <div className="container content">
        <div className="columns">
          <div className="column is-10 is-offset-1">
            <h1 className="title is-size-2 has-text-weight-bold is-bold-light">
              {title}
            </h1>
            <p>{description}Cool</p>
            <PostContent content={content} />
            {tags && tags.length ? (
              <div style={{ marginTop: `4rem` }}>
                <h4>Tags</h4>
                <ul className="taglist">
                  {tags.map((tag) => (
                    <li key={tag + `tag`}>
                      <Link to={`/tags/${kebabCase(tag)}/`}>{tag}</Link>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            ) : null}
            <DiscussionEmbed {...disqusConfig} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};



const BlogPost = ({ data }) => {
  const { markdownRemark: post } = data;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Location>
        {({ location }) => (
          <BlogPostTemplate
            content={post.html}
            contentComponent={HTMLContent}
            description={post.frontmatter.description}
            helmet={
              <Helmet titleTemplate="%s | Blog">
                <title>{`${post.frontmatter.title}`}</title>
                <meta
                  name="description"
                  content={`${post.frontmatter.description}`}
                />
              </Helmet>
            }
            tags={post.frontmatter.tags}
            title={post.frontmatter.title}
            location={location}
          />
        )}
      </Location>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

However, when someone left a comment and I click the "Reply to {somebody}" button in the notification email, it still opens the localhost, rather than the real website link.

Comment: why closing? I'm happy to learn.

Comment: Quick reminder - there's no need to add "please help" pleading to your questions. Succinctness is preferred here, and some readers will interpret this as needy begging.

Comment: thanks @halfer I take the "please help" as a politely ask, hopefully it doesn't violate SOF's policies.

Comment: It's worth noting that language means how it is heard, not how it is meant. The various variations on "please help me out" sound to me like begging. There's probably not a policy on begging, but it's nicer if future readers don't have to wade through that material. Here in the UK, one would have to be in a state of some desperation, kneeling on the ground, and with one's hands clasped together in a state of earnest supplication. I presume you don't talk to your colleagues like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I'd like to break the answer into 4 parts:

1. How does the localhost url sneak into the comment's url?

The localhost url sneaked into the comment's url when I was commenting my article in a localhost development environment.
So to prevent this from happening again, only posting a comment in the production environment. If you did it in localhost environment, how to fix it? Please look at point 3.

2. What does localhost url is called?

The comment url is called [Discussion Url](https://help.disqus.com/en/articles/1717226-how-can-i-update-discussion-urls).

3. Why do we need to know it?

Because this will be the key words for searching any related questions/answers. Without knowing this, I have wasted days for searching this configuration in Disqus.
So in short, it saves you tremendous time.

4. How and where to solve it?

[image]

As you can see there, the 2nd blog Link was using localhost, after I updated to the real website url, the problem was solved.

Hope my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `url` to the `disqusConfig` of the current page disqus is located. In Gatsby, you can expect the location prop to be available to you on every page thanks to its use of @reach/router.

In your component:

```
import {Disqus} from "gatsby-plugin-disqus";

const Article = (props) => {

  let disqusConfig = {
    url: props.location.href,
    identifier: props.your.identifier.source,
    title: props.your.title.source,
  };

  return (
    <div className="article">
      <h1>Article title</h1>
      <div>Article text</div>
      <Disqus config={disqusConfig} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Plugin config:

```
  {
    resolve: `gatsby-plugin-disqus`,
    options: {
      shortname: `your-short-name`
    }
  }
```

Note: you can't use something like `window.location` because there is no `window` during build time (there is no browser server side).

Comment: hi Albert, where is the plugin config? I have .env file where I specify the GATSBY_DISQUS_NAME, is it the same thing?

Comment: In gatsby-config.js, see https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-a-plugin-in-your-site
You can use environment variables in there, examples https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/#example-of-using-an-environment-variable

Comment: also, I updated my post to include my code, I do not have a props as input. How could I get it?

Comment: hi Albert, do you have a moment to answer my question? How could I pass in props beside the already existing parameters in my component? I have updated the code to demo what I mean here. thanks

Comment: Also, I checked by default, Gatsby doesn't use Reach/Router as I have checked its package.json. So do you mean that I need to install it?

Comment: You are destructering props into content, contentComponent, description, tags, title, helmet. If your template is used by gatsby-node.js then you should be able to add it. Please read https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/location-data-from-props.
The dependency on reach/router is here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/package.json#L23

Comment: hi Logan, I have managed to use Location from Reach/Router, however the problem persists. Could you please help? I will update my code in 1 minute.

Comment: Hi Logan, I have updated the code which includes all changes and components.

Comment: this issue looks more like a Disqus configuration issue, rather than the code side config issue.